# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'length') but code works as intended

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

i tried to make this code work

```
let itCompanies = ["Facebook", "Google", "Microsoft", "Apple", "IBM", "Oracle", "Amazon"];

let oInCompany = itCompanies.forEach((element) => { 
var theElement = element.match(/o/gi); 
if (theElement.length > 1) { return console.log(element); 
 } 
});

// the result is code returning the element name into console
```

the code works as intended, but it shows error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'length')
    at main.js:53:18
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at main.js:51:30
```

does it mean the .length is null? but the code works as intended.

i just need explanation for the error, is it my syntax or what?

i can't understand what does it, meanwhile my code works just fine. is there possibilities of it gonna gone wrong somewhere in the future along the road?

Comment: No, it means that `theElement` is null. For instance when you try to match your string `"Apple"` with your regex. As there is no `o` in `"Apple"` the regex doesn't match, and thus   `.match` returns null ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regular expression /o/gi is looking for the letter "o" in the strings in the itCompanies array, but none of the strings in that array contain more than one "o". Therefore, the String.match() method is returning null, which is causing the error to handle the null you can use this:

```js
  let itCompanies = ["Facebook", "Google", "Microsoft", "Apple", "IBM", "Oracle", "Amazon"];
    
    let oInCompany = itCompanies.forEach((element) => { 
      var theElement = element.match(/o/gi); 
      if (theElement && theElement.length > 1) {
        return console.log(element); 
      } 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

`String.prototype.match` can return null if no matches are found. See reference on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match#return_value).

Definitely you should account for the matches array being null.

Comment: ah i see, that's why it does show null. because i use for each and didn't account that for null return. thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

The reason that happens is because in some of words nothing has matched. If nothing has matched the match selector returns null.

You can see here for more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

When the return value is null you are getting null.length. But null has not a property length inside it. Then the error mentioned above is firing.

Change your code like that and it will work properly:

```
let itCompanies = ["Facebook", "Google", "Microsoft", "Apple", "IBM", "Oracle", "Amazon"];

let oInCompany = itCompanies.forEach((element) => { 
var theElement = element.match(/o/gi); 
if (theElement && theElement.length > 1) { return console.log(element); 
 } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You issue comes from the fact that `theElement` may return `null` when using the `.match` method.

Additionally, `forEach` will not return a value.

### One way - `push`

Instead, I've added an array that is `push`ed to:

```js
const itCompanies = ["Facebook", "Google", "Microsoft", "Apple", "IBM", "Oracle", "Amazon"];

let companiesWithOInName = []
itCompanies.forEach((element) => { 
  const theElement = element.match(/o/gi);
  if (theElement) {
    // console.log(element);
    companiesWithOInName.push(element)
  } 
});


console.log(companiesWithOInName);
```

**Note**: that `push` is just one way of doing this.

### Another way - `filter`

Another way people may suggest is the `filter` method:

```js
const itCompanies = ["Facebook", "Google", "Microsoft", "Apple", "IBM", "Oracle", "Amazon"];

const companiesWithOInName = itCompanies.filter((element) => element.match(/o/gi));

console.log(companiesWithOInName);
```

Answer (score -2):

Usually this error occurs when length gets 'null'.
In your case '**if(theElement.length > 1)**'  is getting null, therefore this error is coming.

Comment: Wrong, not `length` is null but `theElement`...